# Why Isn't the Collision on my Prefab Working? How to Put a Sprite on a PreFab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, collision

Whenever I generate the new line of 5 prefabs of cubes which fall to the ground, the collision of the prefab with the ground is not detected and the cubes do not move back into the background. I have no idea what is going on. The collision code is on a script which is a component of the gameObject that generates the prefabs. How do I get the code for a collision with the prefab itself. Plus, how do I assign a sprite to a prefab? I've tried, but Unity does not allow me to do so.

Comment: Consider to improve your question!

Comment: Add a rigidBody component to your gameObjects.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if two objects shall collide, both of them need a collider and at least one of the needs a (non-kinetic) rigidbody. There are 2D and 3D versions of colliders and rigidbodys.

The collision can be caught with e.g. `OnCollisionEnter` in a script attachted to either of the both colliding objects, in your case probably the falling cubes.

Furthermore: you only call something a `prefab` if it is in your assets folder. If you used e.g. `Instantiate` to place an instance of the prefab in the scene, it is called an `instance` (of prefab x).

For the sprite: The object needs to have a `SpriteRenderer`. This has a `sprite` property you can change. If you created the cube prefab by dragging a sprite into the scene and then dragging that gameobject from the scene to the assets folder, your cubes will have a `SpriteRenderer` that you can access.

(I assume with `cube` you mean a flat square when working in 2D.)